# How should I structure working copies for SVN?

Tags: svn

My local SVN tree of working copies is set up to match the directory structure of the repository. In other words, it has trunks, branches, and tags folders all over the place. Is this a good way to set up the working copies? Any better/alternate ideas?

Comment: I guess this depends on what you are doing with your working copy. Do you have an actual *use* for having branches and tags checked out?

Comment: How are you handling different versions/revisions of same working copy?

Comment: This question is really inappropriate here, because it can't be definitively answered, and is going to end up being a discussion. Sorry, but voting to close as "not constructive" for that reason - the FAQ specifically mentions discussion questions not being a good fit for the format here. (You already have two answers that are totally opposite each other; one says the design is good, the other says it's not.)

Comment: @Ken I think that's mainly because the question is very hazy at its present stage. It *could* be clarified into something that invites much less subjective discussion. *looking at the OP*

Comment: @Pekka, agreed. We now have 4 answers, still with mixed support.  I think the OP really has to make this much more specific, or it should be closed.

Comment: @Ken, if you find the question inadequate, what would you recommend for getting a large listing of different ways to do this and then pros and cons so I can decide? It is probably because I don't know enough to ask the question precisely and am looking for the answers to provide general guidance.

Comment: @binarycoder You might consider restructuring the question to ask more specifically: "What specific problems might I encounter by checking out the whole svn tree?"  It still isn't quite to the standard Ken is suggesting, but eliminates the vague "any better/alternate ideas".

Comment: @binarycoder, I don't know of any svn groups off-hand. I know that SO's guidelines say this isn't one (a discussion group, that is), and that discussion-type questions are almost impossible to award an answer to because there are multiple correct answers. (That's probably why the questions aren't appropriate here, BTW - they don't play well with the Q & A design). Unfortunately, [just because you don't know where to ask doesn't make this the right place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128577/172661). You might try the SVN [mailing lists](http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it convenient to have working copy a way similar to yours with a single exception, I do sparse checkout of *branches* and *tags* and populate/drop them upon demand. So the checkout commands are somewhat like

```
$ svn co --depth immediates url_of_myrepo $PWD ;# empty checkout of the repo
$ svn up --set-depth infinity $PWD/myrepo/trunk  ;# sticky dense update of the trunk
...
$ svn up --set-depth infinity $PWD/branches/release_branch ;# sticky dense update of a branch
$ cd $PWD/branches/release_branch
$ svn merge -c 1234 ../../trunk ;# merge a revision from trunk
$ svn commit
$ cd ..
$ svn update --set-depth exclude release_branch ;# sticky wipe out of branch from the working copy
...
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a bit unconventional, I would say.  More typically, you would checkout a working copy of only the project branch/tag/trunk you actually intend to be working on rather than the whole tree.

It makes it somewhat easier to remember what you're making changes to if you don't have the ability to *accidentally* make changes all over the tree at any moment.

So if you have

```
proj
  tags/
    t1/
  branches/
    b1/
    b2/
  trunk/
```

You would do

```
svn checkout proj/trunk proj-trunk
```

If you simultaneously need to work on a branch, checkout a separate working copy:

```
svn checkout proj/branches/b1 proj-b1
```

I will add that sometimes, I will keep a working copy of a small project checked out at the root, so I can examine any tag or branch, but *I don't actually modify this copy*. It's only a quick method to browse the project repository with a proper text editor, etc.  It gets out of sync often though and requires digligent use of `svn up` so I don't use this technique too often.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a good idea in case you need to check out new branches, without checking out the whole repository. You do not actually need to create the folders you will not work on for the moment. For example, you should start with something like `myproject/trunk` when you begin your work on the trunk of the project: in this way, as soon as you want to move to a branch, you can check that out too in its most appropriate path.

I also prefer to make revisions folders after the branch name, like `myproject/branches/mybranch/[rev]` for clarity, when I frequently have to switch between revisions.

Answer (score 1):

What I generally do with Source Control, is to sync to the latest revision of the main branch or whatever is currently being called the main branch. Generally speaking, I only branch or sync to a branch if a specific customer is asking for a specific feature that I don't wish to include in the general available to all build. However if that feature progresses enough such that I would consider moving it to the "GA" build, then I can always merge those changes back into the main branch.

The whole purpose of subversion is to manage your versions and provide a backup. Keeping multiple branches just seems like a great way to quickly become disorganized and really confuse yourself in the future. Also imho defeats the purpose of source control in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy like Michael explained

```
proj
  tags/
  branches/
  trunk/
```

But I also used to add folders for documentation or libraries.